# Booting computer from vdmk file?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have virtualbox running an Os X 10.11 El Capitan VM and I want to be able to boot my computer into OS X, but I can't figure out how to create a usb that my computer will successfully boot to or try to install mac to install to a partition. I've tried transmac and much googling. I was wondering if there is a way to use my existing .vdmk file to boot to a partition on my computer or if there is another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have heard about two possible solutions (but I never try them):
First - you can try convert your .vdmk file into an iso image, and then boot to a partition on your computer.
Second - you can try clone your .vdmk file using Clonezilla (http://clonezilla.org/) and then boot from It.

Hope it works for you.